# How might I obtain the IContextMenu that is displayed in an IShellView context menu?

Tags: c++, windows, com, windows-shell

Building a file open dialog replacement.  Much of it works now, but I would like to generate the view-mode drop-down for the toolbar directly from the shell view object.

Looking at IShellView2, I can see IShellView2::GetView() will give me the FOLDERVIEWMODE's supported.  However, that doesn't give me the names of these modes, nor format that popup menu for me, nor immediately give me a way to actually set one of those modes (it would appear it is necessary to destroy the shell view window and create a replacement one for the current folder and specify the new FOLDERVIEWMODE desired... yeesh).

At any rate, if one right clicks on an IShellView window, one gets a context menu, the first submenu of which is exactly what I want to place in my drop-down toolbar button (ie. the "view" fly-out menu (e.g. Small Icons, Medium Icons, etc.)).

It seems like there ought to be a way to grab that submenu directly from the IShellView, rather than having to hardcode my values (and that way, if a given instance of IShellView supports extra view modes, they'd be there.  Similarly, those which should be disabled would be, since it would all be under the IShellView's control).

I have read Raymond Chen's excellent [How to host an IContextMenu](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/20/231739.aspx).  Unfortunately, that just gives me a very simplistic context menu - the one for the folder itself, or for a file in a given folder, but NOT the context menu for the IShellView's shell view window (from which I might obtain the view fly-out).

I have tried the following, based on Chen's article:

```
CComQIPtr<IContextMenu> pcm(m_shell_view); // <<-- FAIL resulting pointer is NULL <<<

// create a blank menu
CMenu menu;
if (!menu.CreatePopupMenu())
    throw CContextException("Unable to create an empty menu in which to store the context menu: ");

// obtain the full popup menu we need
if (FAILED(m_hresult = pcm->QueryContextMenu(menu, 0, SCRATCH_QCM_FIRST, SCRATCH_QCM_LAST, CMF_NORMAL)))
    throw CLabeledException("Unable to query the context menu for the current folder");

// display the menu to the user
// menu.getsubmenu
::TrackPopupMenu(menu, ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_MENUDROPALIGNMENT)|TPM_TOPALIGN|TPM_LEFTBUTTON, pt.x, pt.y, 0, m_shell_view_hwnd, NULL);
```

Unfortunately, the attempt to query the m_shell_view (which is an IShellView*) for its IContextMenu interface fails.  This "works":

```
// retrieve our current folder's PIDL
PidlUtils::Pidl pidl(m_folder);

// get the context menu for the current folder
CComPtr<IContextMenu> pcm;
if (FAILED(m_hresult = GetUIObjectOf(m_owner->m_hWnd, pidl, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pcm))))
    throw CLabeledException("Unable to obtain the PIDL for the current folder");
```

But here I get only a very few options in the context menu (Open, Explore, ...).  Not the detailed context menu that I get if I simply right click on the shell view itself.

I'm out of ideas as to how to proceed.  Help?!  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try IShellView::GetItemObject with SVGIO_BACKGROUND as uItem to get a IContextMenu on the view object : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774832%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I don't suppose you have any ideas of how to ensure that I can get the view submenu regardless of OS I'm running under (both version and language).

Comment: Sorry. I really doubt it's possible, the whole build the win32 menu to enumerate options seems very low level. It seems that it's build for the purpose of building menus, not poking in them (but I may be wrong )

Answer (score 0):

There is the [SHCreateDefaultContextMenu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Vista an up) that may be of help. [Bjarke Viksoe](http://www.viksoe.dk/) website contains great info as well.
SVGIO_BACKGROUND will get you the background context menu of the shell view. You may need to call repeatedly pShellView->SelectItem for each PIDL you may have, then do the GetUIObjectOf call (then QI for IContextMenu, create a menu, call IContextMenu(3)::QueryContextMenu and finally display it with TrackPopupMenu).